# ¿Que función de VBA me puede ayudar para alinear todos los datos respecto a una columna?

Tags: excel, vba

He estado desarrollando una macro la cuál consiste en obtener datos de una web de la empresa, ya estoy en los pasos finales pero me he atorado en este detalle desde hace dos semanas; el caso es el siguiente:

Tengo que evaluar si se encuentra una "D" en ciertas coordenadas y en caso que sí me tiene que arrojar 13 caracteres por lo que ciertas celdas se llenan y otras no; esa parte de mi código es la siguiente:

```vb
For x = 2 To Fin Step 1
  If Cells(x, 1) = "" Then
  Exit For
  End If

A = Sess0.screen.getstring(12, 10, 1)
B = Sess0.screen.getstring(14, 10, 1)
C = Sess0.screen.getstring(16, 10, 1)
D = Sess0.screen.getstring(18, 10, 1)
E = Sess0.screen.getstring(20, 10, 1)
F = Sess0.screen.getstring(22, 10, 1)
G = Sess0.screen.getstring(24, 10, 1)
H = Sess0.screen.getstring(26, 10, 1)
I = Sess0.screen.getstring(28, 10, 1)
J = Sess0.screen.getstring(30, 10, 1)
K = Sess0.screen.getstring(32, 10, 1)
L = Sess0.screen.getstring(34, 10, 1)
M = Sess0.screen.getstring(36, 10, 1)
N = Sess0.screen.getstring(38, 10, 1)
O = Sess0.screen.getstring(40, 10, 1)


If A = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 2) = Sess0.screen.getstring(12, 10, 13)
End If

If B = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 2) = Sess0.screen.getstring(14, 10, 13)
End If

If C = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 3) = Sess0.screen.getstring(16, 10, 13)
End If

If D = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 4).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(18, 10, 13)
End If

If E = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 5).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(20, 10, 13)
End If

If F = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 6).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(22, 10, 13)
End If

If G = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 7).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(24, 10, 13)
End If

If H = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 8).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(26, 10, 13)
End If

If I = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 9).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(28, 10, 13)
End If

If J = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 10).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(30, 10, 13)
End If

If K = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 11).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(32, 10, 13)
End If

If L = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 12).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(34, 10, 13)
End If

If M = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 13).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(36, 10, 13)
End If

If N = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 14).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(38, 10, 13)
End If

If O = "D" Then
 Cells(x, 15).Value = Sess0.screen.getstring(40, 10, 13)
End If
```

Como se ve una vez que ya tengo los 13 caracteres lo que hago ahora es que me arroje esos caracteres en la celda que vaya contando con el For y en la columna que le indique, dada esta situación todos los datos me quedan desordenados por lo que quiero ordenarlos y me gustaría que me pudieran apoyar en esa parte, con una función que me alinee todos esos datos respecto a la columna 2.

Comment: Sobre la edición: 1) Stack Snippet sólo debe usarse para código HTML/JavaScript/CSS 2) En el cuerpo de las preguntas y respuestas sólo debe incluirse lo necesario para que la publicación sea clara, no saludos, despedidas, firmas, citas literarias, lemas.

Comment: Sobre la pregunta: Por favor incluye una breve descripción de lo que has buscado intentado para resolver tu duda y señala en qué parte te has quedado atorado.

Answer (score 0):

Para alinear los datos de una columna utiliza esto:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Columns("B:B").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

Sustituye XlLeft por Xlcenter o XlRight dependiendo de hacia donde quieras alinear los datos.

También tendrás que modificar Sheets(2) por tu hoja y Columns("B:B") por la columna que quieras ordenar.